# ngRepeat, JSON, angularJS - duplicates are not allowed - via template in directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, controller, directive

**UPDATE:**

> I found that if I'm passing the JSON file in controller like this:

```
controller('dynamicMenuCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.mainmenu2 = [
            {
                "id": "bananas",
                "title": "Bananas",
                "href": "#/bananas",
                "li-class": "menu-element"
            },
            {
                "id": "apples",
                "title": "Apples",
                "li-class": "dropdown"
                "submenu": [
                    {
                        "id": "apple-lot",
                        "title": "Apples lots",
                        "href": "#/apples/lot"                  
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "apple-series",
                        "title": "Apples series",
                        "href": "#/apples/series"
                    }               
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "cherries",
                "title": "Cherries",
                "href": "#/cherries",
                "li-class": "menu-element"
            }
        ]

        });
```

> instead of getting it via $http.get

my navigation-bar is working properly.
I'm calling it in my HTML as:

```
<li ng-repeat=item in mainmenu2>"
```

**UPDATE 2:**
If you are using MVC app, you have to `register JSON` file in `Web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Then all will be fine

---

I have a problem, I have a JSON file:

```
{
    "mainmenu": [
        {
            "id": "bananas",
            "title": "Bananas",
            "href": "#/bananas",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        },
        {
            "id": "apples",
            "title": "Apples",
            "li-class": "dropdown"
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "id": "apple-lot",
                    "title": "Apples lots",
                    "href": "#/apples/lot"                  
                },
                {
                    "id": "apple-series",
                    "title": "Apples series",
                    "href": "#/apples/series"
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cherries",
            "title": "Cherries",
            "href": "#/cherries",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make a navigation bar from this JSON file.
I'm using AngularJS to make this (only Angular is allowed in this case).

I made an controller to get this JSON file:

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').controller('dynamicMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('MenuItems.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.mainmenu = data;
    });
```

Then I want to make an navigation bar in my HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="nav-bar" style="margin-bottom: 0.5%">"
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="navbar-brand">TITLE</span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <span class="navbar-brand">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in mainmenu">
                            <a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> <!-- /.nav navbar-nav -->
                </span> <!-- /.navbar-brand -->
            </div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse-->
        </div> <!-- /.container-fluid-->
    </nav>
```

Then I'm getting an error Error:

```
[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in mainmenu, Duplicate key: string:<, Duplicate value: "<"
```

I tried to use an expression `trackby $index` but it's not rendering in a way I want. There is a looooot of copies of something but I don't know what is wrong.
Maybe I have something wrong in my JSON file or in Controller?

**EDIT: Can you see and edit this plunkr?**
http://plnkr.co/edit/U1xG2E4ys7SGz7WxBtvq?p=preview

It also didn't work, maybe I'm writing something wrong?
I also corrected my JSON file in this post, and the error expression

**EDIT2:
What if I want to make the HTML via directive?**

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').directive('menuTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top\" role=\"navigation\" id=\"nav-bar\" style=\"margin-bottom: 0.5%\">"
                        + "<div class=\"container-fluid\">"
                            + "<div class=\"navbar-header\">"
                                + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\">TITLE</span>"
                            + "</div>"
                            + "<div class=\"collapse navbar-collapse\">"
                                + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\">"
                                        + "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">"
                                            + "<li ng-repeat=\"item in mainmenu\">"
                                                + "<a href=\"{{item.href}}\">{{item.title}}</a>"
                                            +"</li>"
                                        +"</ul> <!-- /.nav navbar-nav -->"
                                    +"</span> <!-- /.navbar-brand -->"
                                +"</div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse-->"
                            +"</div> <!-- /.container-fluid-->"
                        +"</nav>"
           };
}]);
```

**EDIT 3: I updated my plunkr and now it's working:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/U1xG2E4ys7SGz7WxBtvq?p=preview

I created also a directive and it also working.
I don't know why it's working in Plunkr, but didn't in my project :(

Comment: can you provide plunkr?

Comment: @vp_arth, from OP: _I tried to use an expression trackby $index but it's not rendering in a way I want._

Comment: Actual error is: `Repeater: item in content, Duplicate key: string:<` You iterate something wrong...

Comment: `Repeater: item in mainmenu` - I corrected this line, because `content` was my previous name of `mainmenu` - Sorry

Comment: instead using one solution in plunker you try use all, and also you include angular after custom script, this works: http://plnkr.co/edit/bZrw14kuxvvCXVmDCW5a?p=preview

Comment: I made an update, could u peek?

Comment: @karolinka, i not see any errors

Answer (score 4):

Data you are getting is an object which contains an `mainmenu` key which is array of objects. So in your controller use:

```
$http.get('MenuItems.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.mainmenu = data.mainmenu;
    });
```

Further your `mainmenu` array contains some object which have donot have `href` and `title` values but it has `submenu` property (array too)which contains `href` and title `values`.

Use this :

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in mainmenu track by $index">
    <a ng-if="!item.submenu" href="{{item.href}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    <a ng-if="item.submenu">{{item.title}}
      <ul ng-repeat="subitem in item.submenu">
       <li>
         <a href="{{subitem.href}}">{{subitem.title}}</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this

```
<span ng-repeat="motto in mottos"> {{motto}} </span>
```

try something like this

```
<span ng-repeat="motto in mottos track by $index"> {{motto}} </span>
```

you can see this in more detail on [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) page

P.S. this is posible duplicate question of stack overflow question

Comment: I tried this, but something is wrong. I'm getting an empty `<a class="ng-binding" href=""></a>` items (and there is a lot of this items, I don't know why)

**edit** - I read a lot of similar topics and I didn't find the answer :(

Comment: There some issue with JSON you are using and use mainmenu.mainmenu in ng-repeat or you can just fix the json

Comment: I tried with mainmenu.mainmenu and there is nothing in my navigation-bar `<span class="navbar-brand">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
</span>`

Comment: Create plunker or fiddle if possible

Answer (score 3):

There are few problems in your code:

1) JSON is not valid. This is the valid JSON:

```
{
    "mainmenu": [
        {
            "id": "bananas",
            "title": "Bananas",
            "href": "#/bananas",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        },
        {
            "id": "apples",
            "title": "Apples",
            "li-class": "dropdown",
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "id": "apple-lot",
                    "title": "Apples lots",
                    "href": "#/apples/lot"
                },
                {
                    "id": "apple-series",
                    "title": "Apples series",
                    "href": "#/apples/series"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cherries",
            "title": "Cherries",
            "href": "#/cherries",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        }
    ]
}
```

2) `$scope.mainmenu` has itself a `mainmenu` key which is array, so in ng-repeat on the `mainmenu` key as:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in mainmenu.mainmenu">
```

Editing: Using `$http.get` to get the json.

See the plunkr: "http://plnkr.co/edit/Kcl2uVeWg03bawagdQpm?p=preview"

Comment: your plunkr not load json

Comment: Yea because i don't have url for the json, it has to be hard coded you see.

Comment: in plunkr you can create file, and load it

Comment: Yes we can but main logic of the question is how to use it after it has been successfully loaded. The technique of loading json can be anyway changed by the OP.

Comment: nope, main problem in how use result from success callback